# Behaviour of `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Lets say I have the following 2 classes.

```
class A {
  private B b;

  @Transactional
  public void a(){
    b.b();
    //do a stuff
    throw new RuntimeException("oops");
  }
}

class B {
  @Transactional
  public void b(){
    //do b stuff
  }
}
```

In this case will the method `b()` (or b stuff) be rolled back as well?

Comment: everything that happens in an transaction will be rolled back

Comment: It depends on How your Transaction is defined

Comment: @Jens what do you mean? All other attributes of `@Transactional` are default here.

Comment: I am not sure if nested `@Transactional` is allowed in default

Comment: @Jens, nested Transactional is allowed in default. Nested Trasanctional will also be defaulted to REQUIRED same as its parent Transactional method

Answer (score 3):

In your case it will be rolled back.

If your `B b;` is autowired by Spring (in your case it seems it's not) and `@Transactional` on the `b()` method has propagation REQUIRES_NEW (currently it default - REQUIRE) which means don't use existing transaction but start a new so only in this case commit on `b()` is not rolled back.